Please identify these SMD's
Please help me to identify some SMD components.
IC1

IC2

IC3

IC4


As per Component Identification Question Guidelines, please "only one component per question." (Also type out the text, add an 'identification' tag, etc.)

And we need dimensions on all the parts.

I've put an answer for IC1. Please move the remaining parts into seperate questions as per the guidelines linked above.

IC3 is SGM44599 from SG-Micro (you would need to measure if it is the 2.5x2.5mm or 3x3mm package). I can post that as an answer once you split the question up.

IC4 is TPS562201.

IC2 is QX Micro QX5241A - no easily linkable datasheet as its a relatively obscure Chinese company.

@TomCarpenter If you're answering the rest of the question in the comments, you might as well just post an answer for all parts. Why would OP split up the question now?

@nanash1 I did wonder that.

The first part, IC1 is TLV62130 from Texas Instruments. A DC-DC step-down converter in a 3x3mm QFN16 package.
From the datasheet, device marking is VUNI

The TI is Texas Instruments, and the rest is tracability codes.
